# C++ equivalent of C# OOP if(Boy b is Student)

Tags: c#, c++, oop

[image]

I am trying to implement the system above using C++. Previously, I am using C# and OOP to do my programs, so this will be my first time using C++ and I know there is some differences between these two languages. 
What I am trying to do is I want to count number of voters in list of members from Logbook class.

In C#, i will use

```csharp
foreach(Member m in _members) {
    if(Member m is Voter) {
        votercount++;
    }
}
```

However, i am not sure if in cpp, this implement is correct?
In my Logbook.h file

```cpp
class Logbook
{
private:
    std::list<Member> _members;
```

In my Logbook.cpp file:

```cpp
int Logbook::CandidateCount() {
  int membercount;
  for(Member m: _members) {
    if (Member* m=dynamic_cast<const Member*>(&Candidate)) membercount++;
  }
  return membercount;
}
```

It display an error at `&Candidate` where it says identifier Candidate is undefined. Is it because Logbook class can't reach to Candidate class?

Any replies and help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In C#, you could also used `members.OfType<Voter>().Count()`

Comment: @StuartLC thanks for the input! but is my implement in terms of c++ makes sense?

Comment: Some people discourage use of `dynamic_cast` and RTTI in general.

Comment: What type is `_members`? How can we understand the question without knowing that?

Comment: @Galik Hi, _members is used to represent the list, so it would be like:

class Logbook
{
private:
 std::list<Member> _members;

Comment: If candidates are not counted as members, why are they Members? It looks like you're working around a flaw in the design when you should be fixing the design.

Comment: @hopeestheim In that case `std::list<Members>` can only contain `Members`. You can't put any subtypes into it. If you try it will copy only the part of the subtype that **is a** `Member` and the rest will get "sliced" off.

Comment: @molbdnilo Hi, Candidates are member, but in the end i want to print out, how many candidates, voters and members separately.

Comment: If you want to use *polymorphism* in `C++` you have to use *pointers* or *references*. Preferably *smart pointers* like `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Member>>`.

Comment: Also can you put the definition of `_members` into the question?

Comment: @Galik already update the question, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you are doing wrong here. First you are not initializing your counting variable so it will start off using some random value (it maybe zero or maybe something else).

Next you need to store *pointers* to the members of your list because in `C++` polymorphism only works through *pointers*. If the list is responsible for deleting its elements (usual) then you should use a smart pointer like [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
class Logbook {
public:
    int CandidateCount();

    // virtual destructor is (usually) important for polymorphic types
    virtual ~Logbook() = default;

    // store pointers in your list    
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<class Member>> members;
};
```

Then you can iterate through that list trying to *dynamically cast* each pointer to the type you want to count. If it returns a valid *pointer* then you know it is of that type. Otherwise a `nullptr` will be returned:

```
class Member: public Logbook {};
class Candidate: public Member {};
class Voter: public Member {};

int Logbook::CandidateCount()
{
    int membercount = 0; // initialize this!!!!

    for(auto& m : members) { // use reference here to avoid making a copy

        if(dynamic_cast<Candidate*>(m.get()))
            membercount++;
    }

    return membercount;
}
```

**Note:** If you want to do more than just *count* your *candidates* you can keep the pointer obtained from the *dynamic cast* like this:

```
class Candidate: public Member { public: void do_something(){} };

int Logbook::CandidateCount()
{
    int membercount = 0; // initialize this!!!!

    for(auto& m : members) { // use reference here to avoid making a copy

        if(auto c = dynamic_cast<Candidate*>(m.get())) {
            membercount++;

            // c is not nullptr and is type Candidate*    
            c->do_something(); // use your Candidate like this
        }
    }

    return membercount;
}
```

Comment: @Malik First of all thanks for your explanation, it is very easy to understand. Does that means if I want to access the Candidate class methods, i have to iterate as the way above?
And there is several new keywords shown, is auto keyword used for compiler to auto detect datatype?
and why m.get() is used here?

Comment: @hopeestheim Yes. But if you want to actually use them, you need to keep the pointer. So use `if(auto c = dynamic_cast<Candidate*>(m.get())) {/* use c here */}`

Comment: @hopeestheim In that case `c` will be of type `Candidate*`.

Comment: Thanks Galik! you have been most helpful

Comment: @hopeestheim Yes `auto` is a short cut you can use that tells the compiler to *detect* the type. You can only use it where the compiler has all the information to detect the type. Also `m.get()` is used because `m` is a *smart pointer* of type `std::unique_ptr<Member>`. The way to get the pointer it is managing is to call its `get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Logbook::CandidateCount()
{
    int membercount{};
    for(auto const &m : _members) {
       if (dynamic_cast<Member*>(m))
           ++membercount;
    }
    return membercount;
}
```

Comment: May I know at which part of the code that it checks if the type is of Candidate class?

Comment: `if (dynamic_cast<Member*>(m))` tries to cast to `Member*`. If you want to try to cast to `Candidate*`: `if (dynamic_cast<Candidate*>(m))`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using RTTI and `dynamic_cast`s in C++, and instead think of a way to implement what you're doing using a different approach, namely by exploiting the OOP nature of the language.

You already have two classes that both inherit from `Member`, so you could just add a `CountMember(int& voterCount)` method that lets each member log itself in. You then just call that method for each member you have. Something like this:

```
class Member {
public:
  virtual void countMember(int& voterCount) = 0;
};

class Candidate : public Member {
public:
  void countMember(int&) override {}
};

class Voter : public Member {
public:
  void countMember(int& voterCount) override {
    voterCount++;
  }
};

class Logbook {
private:
  std::list<Member> _members;
public:
  int CandidateCount() {
    int votercount = 0;
    for(auto& member : _members) {
      member.countMember(votercount);
    }
    return votercount;
  }
};
```

This makes it easy to add custom behaviors in the case new classes were to be added.

Comment: Hi, yes this works too, quite similar with c# oop inheritance method i learnt before!